# Docker Lists No "Dangling" Images

Tags: docker

I've finished work on a machine's docker setup, and now would like to remove the extra images I'm no longer using to reclaim that disk space. However, the following command I've located returns nothing, even though there are easily 20+ images without a container:

```
docker images --filter "dangling=true" -q
```

Is this a recent docker change that I'm not aware of?

---

```
root@server:~# docker version
Client:
 Version:      1.12.0
 API version:  1.24
 Go version:   go1.6.3
 Git commit:   8eab29e
 Built:        Thu Jul 28 22:11:10 2016
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      1.12.0
 API version:  1.24
 Go version:   go1.6.3
 Git commit:   8eab29e
 Built:        Thu Jul 28 22:11:10 2016
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

root@server:~# docker info
Containers: 10
 Running: 9
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 1
Images: 44
Server Version: 1.12.0
Storage Driver: aufs
 Root Dir: /var/lib/docker/aufs
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Dirs: 224
 Dirperm1 Supported: true
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: null bridge host overlay
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Security Options: apparmor seccomp
Kernel Version: 4.4.0-34-generic
Operating System: Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 3
Total Memory: 992.2 MiB
Name: vps1
ID: AVQ7:XQVN:KDDU:SS3J:GYXH:Q5OI:TUUF:4MLO:EJJK:L3PL:XMLF:MPZ5
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
WARNING: No swap limit support
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
```

Comment: As a temporary workaround `docker rmi \`docker images -q\`` works as docker won't delete any images currently in use without the -f flag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dangling filter finds untagged images([docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/images/#/filtering)), like this one:

```
bash$ docker images
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
<none>              <none>              ecbce29c506e        19 hours ago        88.23 MB
```

I didn't see any filters that looked at running state, so your workaround is a good approach to delete all images (even with tags) that are not in use.

```
docker rmi $(docker images -q)
```

Comment: How do you know that image is untagged? `docker images` lists all the images I have ever downloaded, not just ones that are associated with containers.

Comment: I'm pointing at (or trying to) the `<none>` value in the `REPOSITORY` and `TAG` columns.